# Using curl for downloading Android Source code

Tags: android, curl, repository

What is the use of the below two commands :

> $ curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo
>
> repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

I have already done this in the WORKING_DIRECTORY for one Download.Now I want to use the same repo and same manifest but in some other folder (out side WORKING_DIRECTORY).

Where can I see the Android Manifest file and what does it signifies ?

Is it mandatory to run the above two commands in the new directory , where my repo is already exported in the PATH.

thnx and Rgds,
Rp

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it is very specific and would be better answered here: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `repo` is for developers only, [android.se] for users. I doubt that it is better off over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repo` is a tool to use multiple [`git`](http://git-scm.com/) repositories as one big meta repository.

> $ curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo

Downloads (installs) the `repo` tool into your `bin` directory (used roughly like `Program Files` in Windows). That step is required only once. Afterwards you should be able to use `repo` from the command line in every directory.

> $ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

Initiates such a meta repository based on the manifest xml file ([content of `default.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/master/default.xml)). That file contains a list of git repositories and paths for them. `repo init` does more or less `git clone` for each specified git.

> $ repo sync

goes through all git repositories and downloads & updates their content in the directories that were created by the previous command. You could do `git pull --rebase` for each git yourself but that would take quite the time since Android consists of 40 or so git repositories.

Comment: @Raulp in `.repo/manifest.xml`. That's a hidden directory so you might need to enable showing them if you use a file browser. `cat .repo/manifest.xml` shows you the file on the command line.

Comment: i cant find this in my home directory.is it in home or in WORKING_DIRECTORY(refering to android downloading source code page).Do i need to do repo init for it to be viewed?

Comment: @Raulp `repo init` creates the `.repo` directory in your current working directory. That directory defines the "repo" and each one should have a `manifest.xml` file and a lot of git files. The `repo` tool that you download with `curl` is in `~/bin/` (shortcut for `/home/[your username]/bin/`)

Answer (score 1):

The first command (curl), if performed without modification, needs only be run once on your system (unless the repo tool is updated, in which case you must run it again to get the latest). This is because its output, the repo command, is not in your current directory, it's relative to youor home directory instead.

The "repo" command must be run again when you wish to download the repo to a new working tree.